# ladder, 1 or 2 rungs at a time, recursion / fibonacci error

Tags: java, recursion, fibonacci, ladder-logic

I know there are a lot of already existing questions about this problem, but I haven't found anything that answers mine. My recursion is working fine for lower numbers (I tried int 10) but when I expand it to 100, it becomes exactly one step lower than it should. Not sure why.

My code:

```
public BigDecimal distinctLadderPaths(int rungs) {
    if (rungs < 0)
      throw new ArithmeticException("Ladders can't have negative rungs."); // if negative, throw exception
    else if (rungs == 0)
      return BigDecimal.valueOf(0); //if zero, return zero
    else if (rungs <= 2)
      return BigDecimal.valueOf(rungs); //if 1 or 2, return 1 or 2, respectively
    else{
      long[] f = new long[(rungs + 1)]; //create long Array for memory (f for fibonacci)
      f[0] = 0; //1 steps
      f[1] = 1; //2 steps
      for(int i = 2; i <= rungs; i++) { //loop
        f[i] = f[i - 1] + f[i - 2]; //at each step in the loop, add 1 step lower and 2 steps lower from the number of iterations
      }
      return BigDecimal.valueOf(f[rungs]); //return fibonacci value at final step of the rungs as BigDecimal
    }
  }
```

test code:

```
@Test
  public void testDistinctLadderPaths100 (){
    int rungs = 100;
    BigDecimal expected = new BigDecimal("573147844013817084101");
    BigDecimal result = lp.distinctLadderPaths(rungs);
    assertEquals(expected, result);
  }
```

I'm told the output should be `57314784401381708410`, but I'm getting `3736710778780434371` (which is the fibonacci number at the 99th step). Any ideas why?

Comment: Your algorithm looks fine to me ... could you show us the code around that?

Comment: sure, i'll add right now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

fibonacci seq starts from 1. Sequence is 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8..
so initallize f[0] = f[1] = 1;

Comment: yeah, but if I change f[0] to = 1, the algorithm neither works for 10  nor 100, whereas as it is, it works for 10

Comment: or u just get one step higher.. it might depends on how the questions assumes the value of n

Comment: yeah, but  the problem here is that if I go one step higher, it no longer works for n=10.

Comment: 354224848179261915075 this is what i get as fib(100) and apprently this is the hundredth fibonacci seq if not considered 0 else its 101th.. have a look https://miniwebtool.com/list-of-fibonacci-numbers/?number=101

Comment: yes i agree with the other comment, this is a data type issue.. also "3736710778780434371 (which is the fibonacci number at the 99th step)"  was misleading please edit it if someone refers your question in future

Comment: well now I think you are right actually, because I think given that I'm calculating for tree paths, it's actually the fibonacci results + 1

Answer (score 4):

You are using `long` array to store the data. The range of `long` data type in java is `-9,223,372,036,854,775,808 to 9,223,372,036,854,775,807`. And the result of 100th fab is out of the range of long data type. That's why java is rounding the extra data and giving you the result as  `3736710778780434371`. Try using any other data type it will work fine. There is no issue in the logic, it's the issue of data type.

A working example might look like this:

```
BigInteger[] f = new BigInteger[(rungs + 1)]; //create BigInteger Array for memory (f for fibonacci)
      f[0] = BigInteger.valueOf(1); //1 steps
      f[1] = BigInteger.valueOf(1); //2 steps
      for(int i = 2; i <= rungs; i++) { //loop
        f[i] = f[i - 1].add(f[i - 2]); //at each step in the loop, add 1 step lower and 2 steps lower from the number of iterations
      }
```

Comment: I tried with `double`, `int` and `BigDecimal`, the latter produced the same as long and the former two produced much lower numbers

Comment: @idanicoleherbert See the edited example making use of `BigInteger` and also incorporating the correction in the answer from Harry, it produces the result of `573147844013817084101`